# Hibernate's SequenceStyleGenerator generating sequence below the obtained sequence value

Tags: java, hibernate, jbpm

I'm converting from jBPM 5.4 to jBPM 6 and updating the database of existing values accordingly.

Most of it has gone fine, except in the `WorkItemInfo` table where I'm getting incorrect sequences. The IDs that are being generated are in ranges that are already taken, resulting in unique constraint violations.

After turning on debug logging, I see the following:

```
09:34:53,901 DEBUG [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure] (EJB default - 1) Sequence value obtained: 81993
09:34:53,910 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener] (EJB default - 1) Generated identifier: 81943, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
```

My question is, why is it generating a value lower than the current sequence (81943 vs 81993)? This generated value falls within the range of already used IDs, so causes my unique constraint violations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its appears that WorkItemInfo is using the default Hibernate allocation size.
This means hibernate will most likely be using the TableHiLoGenerator , in short Hibernate will use the sequence and subtract the allocation size.

Your sequence is most likely incrementing by 1 and Hiberate is using the default of 50 for the allocation size. This would explain why your sequence has a difference of 50 (81943 - 50 = 81993).

Short of changing the hibernate code to have an allocation size of 1 (best practice); my recommendation would be to change your sequence to the max value of the key + 1 and increase the increment from 1 to 50.

refrences:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/id/TableHiLoGenerator.html
http://tech.lds.org/wiki/Hibernate%2c_JPA%2c_and_Sequences